# How do I create a new balanced data frame from an imbalanced data one ensuring a random selection of records?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a data frame called `df1` and it will be used for a `machine learning` analysis.

Based on the target variable (`Attrition`), the data frame `df1` has a ratio of YES:NO equal to 60:40

I need to re-create a new data frame from `df1` so that the target variable of Yes/No turns out to be 50:50

My challenge is that I want keep the full number of records where `Attrition`= NO (that is, the 40% of `df1`) in my new data frame and I want R to randomly extract the remaining 50% from the records where `Attrition`=YES in `df1`.

Assuming my new data frame will be called `df2`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 60:40 is **NOT** imbalanced.

But you can use functions from the `caret` package:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
# this downsamples the majority class
df2 <- downSample(x = df1[, -which(colnames(df1)=="Attrition")], 
                         y = df1$Attrition)

#this upsamples the minority class
df2 <- upSample(x = df1[, -which(colnames(df1)=="Attrition")], # supposing that Attrition is the last column in df1 
                         y = df1$Attrition)
```

See [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a possibility to hard code the Attrition column? Just asking because during the process, I will create new features and the Attrition column most probably will not be the last column of the new data frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot! highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Added an example.

```
set.seed(1); df1 <- data.frame(Attrition=c(rep('No', 40), rep('Yes', 60)), val=rnorm(100))
dfNo <- df1[df1$Attrition=='No',]
dfYes <-  df1[df1$Attrition=='Yes',]
dfYes <- dfYes[sample(nrow(dfYes), 40),]
cbind(dfNo, dfYes)
```

Comment: In `sample(nrow(dfYes), 40)`, shouldn't it be `10`? @milan

Comment: I'm not sure. seems like the OP wants all 40 with Attrition equal to 'NO' and in the end there should be as many subjects with Attrition equal to 'No' and 'Yes. But, if I'm wrong, that is what can be changed to the code.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you consider this one as well

Data generation:

```
att<-as.character( c(unlist(rep("NO",60)),unlist(rep("YES",40))))
dt<-data.frame(ID=c(1:100),Attrition=att)
dim(dt)
```

Get the "YES" observations

```
YESdt<-subset(dt,Attrition=="YES",  )  # Get Yes observations
sample(1:nrow(YESdt),nrow(dt)/10)   # Randomly select 10%
```

Update the YESs to NOs

```
YESdt[sample(1:nrow(YESdt),nrow(YESdt)/10),2]<-"NO"
```

Build the new dataset:

```
NOdt<-subset(dt,Attrition=="NO",  )  # Get Yes observations
newDT<-rbind(YESdt,NOdt)
```

size remained the same:

```
nrow(newDT)
```